# Csv is not generated

Tags: csv, cakephp

I am working in CakePHP. I want to generate CSV file. Here I have written code in my view file and the code are :

```
foreach($com as $v)
{
   $this->Csv->addRow($v);
}
$filename='PollAnswer';
echo $this->Csv->render($filename);
```

Here $com written am array like :

```
Array
(
  [0] => Basketball, Total Vote :- 4,Marcel 55-Sandra-Avishek-Dan Guiora
  [1] => Natacion, Total Vote :- 2,Madhumoy-Spanish Sun
  [2] => Rugby, Total Vote :- 1,Ramanuj
  [3] => Hockey, Total Vote :- 1,Victoria Ricciano
)
```

It gives me blank result. So, how can I generate CSV?

**Note :** I am working with CakePHP version 1.3.13

Comment: @arilia  Help me to resolve this problem..

Answer (score 0):

you can integrate it in CakePHP 1.3
Step 1: Save the following file as Csv.php into your app/View/Helper directory

```
<?php
class CsvHelper extends AppHelper
{
var $delimiter = ',';
var $enclosure = '"';
var $filename = 'Export.csv';
var $line = array();
var $buffer;

function CsvHelper()
{
    $this->clear();
}
function clear() 
{
    $this->line = array();
    $this->buffer = fopen('php://temp/maxmemory:'. (5*1024*1024), 'r+');
}

function addField($value) 
{
    $this->line[] = $value;
}

function endRow() 
{
    $this->addRow($this->line);
    $this->line = array();
}

function addRow($row) 
{
    fputcsv($this->buffer, $row, $this->delimiter, $this->enclosure);
}

function renderHeaders() 
{
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header("Content-type:application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-disposition:attachment;filename=".$this->filename);
}

function setFilename($filename) 
{
    $this->filename = $filename;
    if (strtolower(substr($this->filename, -4)) != '.csv') 
    {
        $this->filename .= '.csv';
    }
}

function render($outputHeaders = true, $to_encoding = null, $from_encoding ="auto") 
{
    if ($outputHeaders) 
    {
        if (is_string($outputHeaders)) 
        {
            $this->setFilename($outputHeaders);
        }
        $this->renderHeaders();
    }
    rewind($this->buffer);
    $output = stream_get_contents($this->buffer);

    if ($to_encoding) 
    {
        $output = mb_convert_encoding($output, $to_encoding, $from_encoding);
    }
    return $this->output($output);
}
}
?>
```

Step 2: Add this Helper to your controller:

```
var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form','Csv');
```

Step 3: create a method “download” at controller for eg. homes_controller.php

```
<?php
function download()
{
    $this->set('orders', $this->Order->find('all'));
    $this->layout = null;
    $this->autoLayout = false;
    Configure::write('debug', '0');
}
?>
```

Step 4: put this link on page from where you have to download CSV

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->link('Download',array('controller'=>'homes','action'=>'download'), array('target'=>'_blank'));
?>
```

Step: 5 (final step)
Put this code on View/Homes/download.ctp

```
<?php
 $line= $orders[0]['Order'];
 $this->CSV->addRow(array_keys($line));
 foreach ($orders as $order)
 {
      $line = $order['Order'];
       $this->CSV->addRow($line);
 }
 $filename='orders';
 echo  $this->CSV->render($filename);
?>
```

Thanks , Happy Coding :)